# How do I avoid unwanted recursion in my custom LinkedList implementation?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to insert a new node at the end of the list but it keeps recursing.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run();
    }

    private static void run() {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.add("abc");
        list.add("def");
        list.add("ghi");
        list.add("jkl");
    }
}
```

The add method first checks if the list is empty.

If so, it creates a head node.

Otherwise, it tries to find the end of the list and insert the new node there.

```
public class LinkedList<T> {

    Element head;
    Element terminator = new Element("TERMINATOR", true);

    public void add(T e) {
        Element node = new Element(e);
        if(head==null){
            head = node;
            head.setNext(terminator);
        }
        else {
            Element end = getEnd2();
            end.setNext(node);
        }
    }

    public Element getEnd2() {
        Element tmp;
        while((tmp = head.getNext())!=null){
            System.out.println("tmp:" + tmp.getValue());
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public Element getEnd(){
        Element node = head;
        while(node!=null){
            System.out.println("node:" + node.getValue());
            node = head.getNext();
        }
        return node;
    }

    public Element getHead(){
        return head;
    }
}

public class Element<T>{
    T value;
    Element<T> next;

    boolean terminator;

    Element(T value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    Element(T value, boolean terminator){
        this.value = value;
        this.terminator = terminator;
    }

    public void setNext(Element<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Element getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public T getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public boolean isTerminator() {
        return terminator;
    }

    public void setTerminator(boolean terminator) {
        this.terminator = terminator;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by keeps recursing? What is the result of the code as is? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is infinite :

```
public Element getEnd(){
    Element node = head;
    while(node!=null){
        System.out.println("node:" + node.getValue());
        node = head.getNext(); // head.getNext() always returns the same value
    }
    return node;
}
```

And if you change it to `node = node.getNext()`, your method would just return null.

If you want the last non-null Node, change it to  :

```
public Element getEnd(){
    Element node = head;
    while(node.getNext()!=null){
        System.out.println("node:" + node.getValue());
        node = node.getNext();
    }
    return node;
}
```

`getEnd2()` has the same infinite loop problem, but you can't fix it without making it exactly the same as `getEnd()`, since you can't do the assignment to `node` and the null check in the same statement (since you only want to make the assignment after you verify that you are not assigning null to `node`).

Answer (score 0):

It is not recursing, it is infitie looping on the line:

```
while((tmp = head.getNext())!=null)
```

The condition never changes, so if `head.getNext() != null`, this will loop forever.